# multiple columns listview from Sqlite DB android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm using a DB with three tables, student, answer, question
the answer table contains studentid, questionid, answer 
I built a DB in SQLITE with the three tables, so when the app is loaded, I'm setting that the student goes and check the answer.
The problem is with getting the history from this table, in a ListView, I used an adapter before but that was easy before it's just direct informations displaying from tables, but for the table answer, I have to get the studentid and display the name, get the questionid and display the question itself.
The adapter doesn't work because the class doesn't has the same thing that I want to display, so I made a method that can give me the informations that I want:

```
public ArrayList getTableHisto() {
        ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
        int zise = lst.size();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT Q." + KEY_QUESTION + " , U." + KEY_NOM + " , U." + KEY_PRENOM + " , A." + KEY_DATE + " , " + KEY_REPONSE + " from " + TABLE_QUESTION + " Q, " + TABLE_USER + " U, " + TABLE_ANSWER + " A WHERE Q." + KEY_ID_QUESTION + " = A." + KEY_ID_QUESTION + "AND A." + KEY_MATRICULE + " = U." + KEY_MATRICULE, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
                String nom = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOM)).toString();
             //   String prenom = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRENOM)).toString();
                String quest = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTION)).toString();
                String reponse = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REPONSE)).toString();
                String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)).toString();
                lst.add(nom);
               // lst.add(prenom);
                lst.add(quest);
                lst.add(reponse);
                lst.add(date);


                c.moveToNext();

            }

        }
        return lst;
    }
```

I think it's working because I tried the sql query, but the problem is to adapt it to the ListView that has four columns in the histrow.java:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="nom" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hquest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ques" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hrep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="rep" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="date" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The history's page has only a ListView with id: hist
If someone has any idea, don't hesitate please.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use a customised Adapter or use a CursorAdapter, the latter is probably the easiest as their is no need to customise it.

#### Using a CursorAdapter

If you use a CursorAdapter then rather than building an ArrayList from an extracted Cursor you use the Cursor directly.

You could have :-

```
public Cursor getTableHistoAsCursor() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery(" SELECT Q." + KEY_QUESTION + " , U." + KEY_NOM + " , U." + KEY_PRENOM + " , A." + KEY_DATE + " , " + KEY_REPONSE + " from " + TABLE_QUESTION + " Q, " + TABLE_USER + " U, " + TABLE_ANSWER + " A WHERE Q." + KEY_ID_QUESTION + " = A." + KEY_ID_QUESTION + "AND A." + KEY_MATRICULE + " = U." + KEY_MATRICULE, null);
}
```

The respective Activity could be :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr; //<<<< Note 1
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Cursor mCsr;
    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //<<<< Note 2

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourlistview); //<<<< Note 3
        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);  //<<<< Note 1

        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getTableHistoAsCursor();

        mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                 R.layout.yourlayout, //<<<< Note 2
                 new String[]{KEY_NOM, KEY_QUESTION, KEY_REPONSE, KEY_DATE}, //<<<< Note 4
                 new int[]{R.id.hname, R.id.hquest, R.id.hrep, R.id.hdate}, //<<<< Note 5
                 0
        );
        mListView.setAdapter(mSCA);    
}
```

#### Notes

- Note 1 - Change DatabaseHelper to reflect your databasehelper.
- Note 2 - Change layouts to reflect your layouts.
- Note 3 - Change to get the appropriate listview.
- Note 4 - This is a string array of the column names **from** which the data is to be extracted. There is a direct relationship with Note 5.
- Note 5 - The id's of the Views into which the extracted data (as per Note 4) is to be placed. i.e. the first column is used to place data into the first View, the second column into the second view and so on.

  - `KEY_NOM`, `KEY_QUESTION` etc may need to be further qualified e.g. `DatabaseHelper.KEY_NOM` (Note 1) or changed to use hardcoded strings e.g. `"name"`, `"question"` etc depending upon how there are defined.
- Note 6 - The above is untested code so there may be errors.

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my internship, I will try it now and send you back the answer. Thanks a lot.